# Eventually load member variable value in a non blocking thread safe manner

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, design-patterns, concurrency

I have a class that has a getter method (among others):

```
public class Employee {  

  public EmployeeAccount getAccount() {  
     return this.empAccount;  
  }  
}
```

The problem is that the `empAccount` is initialized by an async call which might return null but **eventually** would return the actual account.
The reason is that the async call method depends on many things and sometimes might return null as it is not ready to give the account yet. Please note that I have no control over this API.
So I was thinking of doing something like:

```
public class Employee {  
   public EmployeeAccount getAccount() {  
      if(this.empAccount != null) {   
         retrieveAccount(); 
      }
       return this.empAccount; 
   }
   private void retrieveAccount() {  
      Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {  
          @Override   
          public void run() {  
             this.empAccount = getAccountFromRemoteSystem(); // <--- this is a blocking call   
          }  
      };  
     t.start();  
}
```

The reason I was aiming towards this is because `getAccount()` is expected to be non-blocking as it is called from a UI thread.
How can I design/structure my code so that it is thread safe? Are there better constructs I can use or some other design pattern?

Comment: If you are going async, you have to actually go all async.  Pass a callback that can then, later, invoke an event on the UI thread when the account comes in, (or an error indication, of course:)..

Comment: @MartinJames:Well I don't really need to show any error to the UI. The data can be displayed when they are available if they are actually needed. I.e. the `getAccount` may not be called more than once from the UI but may be called more if the data are actually needed

Comment: If the method is supposed to be asynchronous, it can't possibly return an EmployeeAccount. It can return a Future<EmployeeAccount>, or take a callback that will be called when the AmployeeAccount is available, but it can't return an EmployeeAccount without blocking. I would leave this method as blocking, and let the UI call it in a background thread if needed, and retry as many times it needs to..

Comment: @JBNizet:The `getAccountFromRemoteSystem` actually is blocked on a `Future<EmployeeAccount>` inside the method. So basically the idea is that it can return null and the UI can still work and the at this point we can still load the data in the background

Comment: Assume the method returns null. How will you implement the caller? With an infinite loop calling the method again and again until the result is not null? That is not a very good strategy, is it?

Comment: Did you try storing your empAccount as an AtomicReference? Then you can safely access it from different threads.

Comment: @JBNizet:There is a guarantee (of the api contract) that eventually the data will be available. It is not possible to always return null.

Answer (score 0):

The answer begets a specification question. Do you specify that an instance of the `Employee` class is *usable* even if that instance's `EmployeeAccount` (you should perhaps rename it to `Account`) is not yet available?

It appears that it is a valid `Employee` instance if the account is *not yet set up*. In that case, it is important to state that in the contract of the `getAccount` method:

```
/** Returns the {@linkplain EmployeeAccount} with this instance. 
    It may be null, if the account is not yet set up at the time of 
    this call. Typically, the clients should retry if this method     
    returns null.

    @return EmployeeAccount if it is available, null otherwise.
*/
public EmployeeAccount getAccount() {
    //
}
```

Deferring the construction of `account` to a later time runs the risk of the account never getting assigned a valid, non-null value for a valid looking `Employee` reference. This is why there's nothing like `final` fields and immutable instances.

If this caveat is something you and your clients are okay with, then I'd go ahead with what you have above. Make sure that the `employee` field is either `volatile` or `AtomicReference`, so that the updates made to it by the background thread that retrieves the real account from a remote/async call are *visible* to the other threads (e.g. the UI thread that calls the getter).